# How can you reuse a class in Entity Framework without using inheritance?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping, entity-framework-6

I have a bunch of simple classes that are referenced from various other classes. For example,

```
class Version {
    // PK is Major, Minor, Build, Revision
    int Major { get; set; }
    int Minor { get; set; }
    int Build { get; set; }
    int Revision { get; set; }
}

class DraftArticle {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    ICollection<Version> AffectedVersions { get; set; }
}

class Article {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    ICollection<Version> AffectedVersions { get; set; }
}

class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {
    System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DraftArticle> DraftArticles { get; set; }
    System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

When used as posted above, Entity Framework will create three tables -- [DraftArticles], [Articles], and [Versions] where the [Versions] table will have the following **extra** columns -- [Discriminator], [DraftArticle_Id],  and [Article_Id].

My goal is to separate the Version records for DraftArticles and Articles into separate tables.

I know this **can** be done using `inheritance` and/or `ComplexType` but I would like to avoid both of those as it necessitates the need for additional classes.

For example, the following additions and modifications work

```
// additions
class DraftArticleVersion : Version { }

class ArticleVersion : Version { }

// modifications
class DraftArticle {
    ...
    ICollection<DraftArticleVersion> AffectedVersions { get; set; }
}

class Article {
    ...
    ICollection<ArticleVersion> AffectedVersions { get; set; }
}

class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DraftArticleVersion>().Map(m => {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("DraftArticleAffectedVersions");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DraftArticleVersion>().Map(m => {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("ArticleAffectedVersions");
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

In addition, when using a framework like `AutoMapper` it requires additional (duplicated) mapping definitions.

***Ideally***, what I would love to see is something along the lines of `ToTable()` being applied at the **Property** level *instead* of at the **Class** level. For example,

```
class Version {
    // PK is Major, Minor, Build, Revision
    ...
}

class DraftArticle {
    ...
    ICollection<Version> AffectedVersions { get; set; }
}

class Article {
    ...
    ICollection<Version> AffectedVersions { get; set; }
}

class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        // somehow apply .ToTable("DraftArticleAffectedVersions") to DraftArticle.AffectedVersions

        // somehow apply .ToTable("ArticleAffectedVersions") to Article.AffectedVersions
    }

    ...
}
```

Does anybody know if this can be done? Are you aware of any other methods to reusing classes **without** the need to created additional classes and/or mappings?

Comment: Are you saying that you want one Version table for the Articles, and another Version table for DraftArticles?

Comment: I suppose part of the problem is I don't know why you want to separate Version into two tables. If Versions are truly unrelated, then they should be separate entities that just happen to have the same fields.

Comment: You will run into maintenance nightmare, Article, Draft etc all are very similar, the correct design would be to have just one table and setup a State field which will say "Draft", "Published", this is how every blog does it. If you want to achieve one to many relations between Article and Draft then you can create a self parent child relation.

Comment: @Fabio -- Correct. Separate tables for the different article types. They just happen to both have Version properties. SO why have to created duplicate classes. Maintenance headache.

Comment: @Vlad274 / @ Akash -- Please explain why the "proper" design is to put them into the same table? They serve different purposes. Maybe I have an "Articles" table that is for KB articles and another "Articles" table for TechnicalNote articles. And the two types of articles are unrelated except for having the same class properties. The question is about avoiding the creation of unnecessary (duplicate) classes. I actually think maintaining distinct classes with the same exact properties is MORE of a maintenance nightmare. Need to make changes more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments are suggesting - you're not going to like the answer, which is that you're trying to do something that doesn't make much sense, so EntityFramework doesn't support it.

By saying both Article and Draft have a list of "Versions", you've told EF that both are referring to the same thing - therefore a single table. But yet you say you want them to refer to different things. Why?

As Akash said, a better (more normalised) design will avoid needing this strange outcome.

Comment: Because in essence they are different -- from an entity perspective. The question is about reusing class definitions and reducing maintenance. I was trying to keep my example simple but I think everyone focused too much on draft vs published article. Maybe a better example would have been Article and Support Ticket. Two *completely* different entities but they both could have completely different collections of Version objects that happen to have the same properties. Wanted to see if I could reuse my Version class. Apparently not...

Comment: Yes, I can see what you want to achieve, which obviously EF doesn't support. How are they "completely different" though? They actually appear to be exactly the same thing, a generalised "Version" which following usual normalisation, should go in one table.

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this after such a long break. Ultimately, while I disagree that keeping them in the same table is the proper approach this answer does address my question in that "EF does not support it" so I will mark it as such.